# verify controller in sms register

Tags: laravel

I created a website with Register  SMS functionality that the contact was sent for to him when registering an identity code and he is also stored in the file name table.

Now what do I need to do to controllerverify until user the contact with his code and activate his account?

Comment: You may provide the code you have tried so we can help you, it seems you have saved the code sent by sms now you have to add a page after the registration to enter the received code

Answer (score 0):

code verifyControlller ::

```
  public function activeUser(Request $request, $phone)

    {
        $code = $request->code;
        $user = User::where('phone', $phone)->whereHas('activitionCode', function ($query , $request) {

            $query->where('code', $request->code)->where('expire', '<', Carbon::now());
        })->first();
        if ($user) {
            $user->active = 1;
            $user->save();
        } else {
            return back()->withErrors(['code', 'code invalide']);
        }
    }
}
```